# TF2: model.predict returning dictionary in Colab but not in local test

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I want to get the activations of some of the layers in my model. I have creates a dictionaty of format

```
layer_act_op = {layer.name: layer.output for layer in model.layers}
```

and then created a model for getting activation as

```
act_model = tf.keras.models.Model(inputs=model.input, outputs=layer_act_op)
```

Now, when I run

```
activation = act_model.predict(data)
```

1. in Colab (with Google Compute Engine backend), `activation` is a dictionary with keys corresponding to the keys in `layer_act_op`
   and activation values
2. in my local PC, when I run this inside a function, `activation` is a list of length equal to the number entries in `layer_act_op`

In both cases, `tf.eagerly_running()` return `True`.

I couldn't figure out why this different behavior. How can I use `model.predict` in local PC and also get a dictionary with activations?

TF Version: 2.2.0rc4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the interesting problem. I have tested it on both colab and local PC (MacOS 10.15). And figure out the output is different between tf2.1(stable) and tf2.2(unstable). Maybe you could check your tf version on your local PC, uninstall the tf2.1, then install nightly version with `pip3 install tf-nightly`.

I test with the script below:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras import Sequential, layers
import numpy as np

print(tf.__version__)
model = Sequential()
model.add(layers.Input(shape=(224, 224, 3)))
model.add(layers.Conv2D(filters=64, kernel_size=5, activation="relu", name='conv1'))
model.add(layers.ReLU(name='relu'))

layer_act_op = {layer.name: layer.output for layer in model.layers}
act_model = tf.keras.models.Model(inputs=model.input, outputs=layer_act_op)

data = np.arange(224*224*3*2).reshape(2, 224, 224, 3)
_ = act_model.predict(data)
print(type(_))
print(_.keys())
```

The outputs:

```sh
2.2.0-dev20200429
2020-05-04 09:37:04.953746: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:142] This TensorFlow binary is optimized with Intel(R) M
KL-DNN to use the following CPU instructions in performance-critical operations:  AVX2 FMA
To enable them in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.
2020-05-04 09:37:04.977887: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:168] XLA service 0x7fd8c0626f20 initialized for platform Ho
st (this does not guarantee that XLA will be used). Devices:
2020-05-04 09:37:04.977916: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:176]   StreamExecutor device (0): Host, Default Version
<class 'dict'>
dict_keys(['conv1', 'relu'])
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. That indeed was the case. I was in tf-2.1 in my local PC, while I was using 2.2 rcs in colab.